# APNS push notification from server

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have web app written in JAVA and I would like to push notifications from my service. I can't use local notifications from browser because I'm targeting on iOS (tablets). So I would like to use a APNs. If I would like to send message to device I need token from this device;). So my question is.

1. How Can I get this token?

Edit:
I have't precise one thing. It is possible to get device's token without any native solution. For example tablet connect to out site, do something and we want to answer useing notification. And how to get token to send this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to use APNS without a native app on the iOS device.  The push notification token is unique for each app on each device - so a token obtained from one app cannot be used with another app on the same device (There is an exception to this, where apps from the same developer can share a token).

Further the push notification service relies upon a digital certificate that is managed by the developer using the Apple developer portal.

Finally, when a push notification is sent to the iOS device, it is actually delivered to the corresponding app for processing - so if there is no native app on the device, there is nothing to process the notification.

You can get the detail on APNS programming in [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194)

Comment: So It isn't possible to that device get token and send to the server and server send notification using this token? And all is without native iOS app.

Comment: No.  APNS needs to communicate with a native app on the iOS device.  If there is no app then there is nothing to register for notifications and nothing to receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can get device token from this method. put this method in your appdelegate.m class.make sure you are running your iOS app in real device if you are running app in virtual device(Simulator),then you can not find device token,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
}
```

Comment: O I have't precise this. I must get this without any native solution. It all must be resolved by browser and http.

Comment: it mean you don't want to use this method. i think there is no such a way by which you can get device token except it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this device token ios application will have to request for registering push notification service,this will result in a dialog asking for permission that this application wants to send you notification if iOS user says yes then device will register for push notification and will be provided a device token.

This device token has to be sent to server by the ios app developer then only server can use this device token and send it to APNS.

to register for push notification from ios device use below method,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
```

if ios user allows says yes then below method will be called which will give you device token which needs to be sent to the server for posting notification from server.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSString * deviceTokenstring = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"device token :%@",deviceTokenstring);
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:REMOTENOTIFICATION_URL,deviceTokenstring]]] delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];

}
```